# Hide animation of Border or TextBlock

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

How I can hide and return back element like Border or TextBlock (when I tap it) with animation? I do it now by changing value of Opacity (from 0 to 1 and vice versa) on "Tapped" event. When I tap it first time it dissapears, and when I tap again it apears, but it works without animation. I want to add some animation, when element dissapears gradaually. I know there is "fadeoutthemeanimation", but I can't configure it as needed

```
<Border Tapped="Border_Tapped" Background="#A5000000" Height="80">
    <TextBlock Text="Test"/>
</Border>

private void Border_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Border b = (Border)sender;

    b.Opacity = b.Opacity == 0.0 ? 1.0 : 0.0;
}
```

I add fadeoutthemeanimation and it works as I want, but I should hold border tapped. I want just tap border and start animation.

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Storyboard SpeedRatio="0.1" x:Name="EnterStoryboard">
            <FadeOutThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="border" />
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard SpeedRatio="0.1" x:Name="ExitStoryboard">
            <FadeInThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="border" />
        </Storyboard>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Border Name="border" Tapped="Border_Tapped" Background="#A5000000" Height="80" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
            PointerEntered="Border_PointerEntered" 
           PointerExited="Border_PointerExited">
         <TextBlock Text="Test" FontSize="40" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White"/>
    </Border>
</StackPanel>

    private void Border_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Border b = (Border)sender;
        b.Opacity = b.Opacity == 0.0 ? 1.0 : 0.0;
    }

    private void Border_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        EnterStoryboard.Begin();
    }

    private void Border_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ExitStoryboard.Begin();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say your TextBlock is this

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="Fade Me" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" Tap="textBlock_Tap" />
```

You can easily do this in blend. Add the Following XAML code to the page Where you have your textblock.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="FadeOutTextBlock">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Name="FadeInTextBlock">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Then in the Tap event handler add the following code

```
private void textBlock_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
     if (textBlock.Opacity == 0.0)
     {
         FadeInTextBlock.Begin();
     }
     else
     {
         FadeOutTextBlock.Begin();
     }
}
```

Now run the app and tap on the TextBlock. :) Hope it helps.

Comment: try using blend for creating animations. Its really easy :)

Comment: blend? really don't know what it is, can you tell me where to read about it?

Comment: [Here](http://wpdevkvk.wordpress.com/2014/07/17/custom-xaml-controllers-i-adding-custom-styles-to-elements/) is one my blog posts. It shows how to create a button style in Blend. I will add how i did this animation very soon. The blog will have more posts about blend in the future. Also search for Blend tutorials on google and youtube. There is plenty to go around. :)

Comment: Here is how i did it in Blend. Includes a video https://wpdevkvk.wordpress.com/2014/07/24/create-a-fade-animation-using-blend/